# Using Selenium keywords to find if any text is in the Element

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I know that there is the following keyword to find if particular text is in the Element:

```
Element Should Contain  <xpath>  <text>
```

But I just want to find if the Element contains any text.
Do I have to use a different keyword or can I use some kind of wildcard for any text?
i.e. Will this be possible?

```
Element Should Contain  <xpath>  *
```

Answer (score 0):

Define what should satisfy "any text" - will an empty string also qualify? If so, you can do `Page Should Contain Element` - it will pass if it's in the page, regardless what its text is.

You could also get the text, and validate it any way you like:

```
${txt}     Get Text    <xpath>
Should Not Be Empty    ${txt}    # etc
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The element is a text box and it should not be empty. I will try the get text method.